# React to window resize event *before* layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, scala.js

Consider the "pixel pipeline" described with a nice colourful diagram at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/

I have an element (a span, let's say) which I would like to resize when the browser window resizes. I am doing so using the `window.onresize` / `window.addEventListener('resize'`

This works and I resize it to fit within the available space. Great. The trouble is, though, that for a brief moment after I resize the window (a sudden resize e.g. a "restore" from full screen to 30% height), a scrollbar shows. I believe it only shows because the pipeline goes through the layout, paint and composite stages once in reaction to the changed size of the window **before** running my `onresize` code, and although nothing other than the window changes size during that cycle, it is enough to make the a scrollbar appear. On the very next cycle I reduce the size of my span to fit the window, and the scrollbar is gone.

For the contrived example of one span I am sure I could use a style specifying a margin or something similar to solve the problem, but for my more general problem I do want to use JavaScript to make the adjustment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can avoid these scrollbars by defining a css on the paret container.. it's a guess but I think this is html or body in your case

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Wolfgang, you're right - that avoids the scrollbar appearing. I will leave the question open for now in the hopes of soliciting answers to the problem of updating the layout before the first layout stage. Because, even with this css, the component itself is momentarily too large for the window and only updates to the correct size a flashy split-second later. Your answer is sensible and immediately applicable though, thanks.